# Log in to website using Active Directory with a two-way trust

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership

We have an ASP.NET website set up using Active Directory as the Membership Provider. The site uses the `Forms` authentication mode and the .NET `Login` control. We recently merged with another company and now they also need access to the site, but they are of course on a different domain. Our IT people have set up the two Active Directories in a two-way trust.
I can log on to their domain using a test account from our network. But when I use the same DOMAIN\username + password combo on my website it does not work.
How can I make our site able to see users on the second domain? Is this not possible using the  `Login` control? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to authenticate against a remote AD domain, via a trust with the built-in provider.  You could setup a second provider which is configured to point at the other domain, and then add addition logic to your Login control to pick the right provider to authenticate against.  I use a similar approach to support "pass-through" authentication of domain users while also support non-domain users with standard forms authentication.

Comment: So I'll have to override the `Authenticate` event and do it all manually. Will my `SQLProvider` `RoleManager` still work with the second AD `MembershipProvider`?